# Maximizing the product of numbers after summing certain set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Let we have three baskets A,B,C. 
And we also have a set of integers X={$x_1$, ..., $x_n$}.
For each $x_i$, we should put it in one of the baskets.

After this, for each basket, we sum every integer in it.
Let's name them as a, b, c perspectively.
Our goal is maximizing the product: $a*b*c$.

For example... let X = {1,1,2,2}
Then the solution will be as following:
A : {1,1}
B : {2}
C : {2}

I think this problem is somewhat similar to knapsack... but different.
Any idea will be really appreciated.

- Extended version : What if the baskets already have integers?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $I$ be the set of items, and let $B$ be the set of bins. For $i\in I$ and $b \in B$, let binary decision variable $y_{i,b}$ indicate whether item $i$ appears in bin $b$.  The problem is to maximize
$$\prod_b \sum_i x_i y_{i,b}$$
subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_b y_{i,b} &= 1 &&\text{for $i \in I$} \\
\end{align}
The nonlinear polynomial objective can be linearized by replacing each product of binary variables with a new binary variable and linear constraints, as described [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables).

For your example, $I=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $B=\{1,2,3\}$, $x_1=x_2=1$, and $x_3=x_4=2$.  Your sample optimal solution is $y_{1,1}=y_{2,1}=y_{3,2}=y_{4,3}=1$, with all other variables $0$.